# intel-Based Assembly Language idiv

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to get `idiv` working properly and I've read you put what you want to divide
such as 25 and then in `ebx` you put what you want to divide by such as 5 then you do

```
idiv ebx
```

which then puts `EAX` = 5 and then `EDX` = 0.

However it doesn't do that in my program the input I do is ***100000000***

**output:**

*Kilobytes: 100000000*

*Megabytes: 1869375819*

Was wondering what am I doing wrong here?

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
;
; initialized data is put in the .data segment
;
segment .data
prompt db "Please enter the number of bytes:", 0
param db "1 = Calculate it in kilobytes", 0Ah, "2 = Calculate it in megabytes", 10, 0
output db "Kilobytes: %d", 0Ah, "MegaBytes: %d", 10, 0
;
;
segment .bss
;
input resd 1
input2 resd 1
choice resd 1
;
; code is put in the .text segment
;
segment .text
    global  asm_main
extern printf
asm_main:
    enter   0,0              
    pusha

    mov eax, prompt
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [input], eax
    mov [input2], eax

    sub esp, 10h
    push dword [output]
    push dword [input2]
    push dword [input]


    mov eax, param
    call print_string
    call read_int

    cmp eax, 1
    je kilobyte; Jump if eax is equal to 1

    cmp eax, 2
    je megabyte; Jump if eax equal to 2

kilobyte:
    pop eax             ; Pop input into eax
    cdq             
    mov ebx, 1024       ; Put 1024 into ebx
    idiv ebx             ; EAX = 100000000/1024 = 97656
    mov [input], eax    ; Move 97656 into var=input
    push dword [input]  ; Put into stack
    jmp megabyte

megabyte:
    pop eax             ; Pop input into eax
    cdq         
    mov ebx, 1048576    ; Put 1048576 into ebx
    idiv ebx             ; EAX = 100000000/1024 = 95
    mov [input2], eax   ; Move 95 into var=input    
    push dword [input]  ; Put into stack
    jmp printOut

printOut:
    mov dword [esp], output
    call printf

    add esp, 4 * 3


    add esp, 10h

    popa
    mov     eax, 0            
    leave                     
    ret
```

**UPDATE**

Well I put in `xor edx, edx` but I am still getting the same output as before. I've looked into my ebook and other sites and it says same thing so I am really unsure of what I am doing wrong. As well tried the `idiv` route with no luck.

Comment: There's nothing called "Intel-based assembly language". Intel has many different architectures with corresponding different assembly language. The question should be tag with `x86`

Comment: Check my answer about additional info about the printing.

Answer (score 6):

## About the division

At  first, for the goal you need (computing MBytes and KBytes) you need unsigned devision actually. So, use `div` instruction instead of `idiv`.

Second, `div` and `idiv` actually divide 64bit number in `edx:eax` by a 32bit number specified as an operand. But your `edx` register contains random number.

So, you have to expand the number in `eax` to 64bit before the division.

For `idiv` use:

```
    cdq       ; convert signed 32bit number in eax into signed 64bit in edx:eax
    idiv  ebx
```

For `div` use:

```
    xor   edx, edx  ; set edx to 0 in order to extend unsigned eax in edx:eax
    div   ebx
```

## About the printint

Your printing code looks wrong:

```
kilobyte:
    pop eax             ; Pop input into eax
    cdq             
    mov ebx, 1024       ; Put 1024 into ebx
    idiv ebx             ; EAX = 100000000/1024 = 97656
    mov [input], eax    ; Move 97656 into var=input
    push dword [input]  ; Put into stack
    jmp megabyte

megabyte:
    pop eax             ; Pop input into eax
    cdq         
    mov ebx, 1048576    ; Put 1048576 into ebx
    idiv ebx             ; EAX = 100000000/1024 = 95
    mov [input2], eax   ; Move 95 into var=input    
    push dword [input]  ; Put into stack
    jmp printOut

printOut:
    mov dword [esp], output
    call printf

    add esp, 4 * 3
```

At first, why to jump to the next address??? The CPU will get there by itself. This is not exactly error, but makes the code less readable and is simply redundant.

```
    mov [input2], eax   ; Move 95 into var=input    
    push dword [input]  ; Put into stack

printOut:
    mov dword [esp], output
    call printf

    add esp, 4 * 3
```

Here you can see, that the result is stored in [input2], but [input] is pushed in the stack. Why? The next instruction `mov dword [esp], output` overwrites the last pushed value in the stack.

Notice that push instruction first decrements `esp` and then stores the pushed value at [esp]. Here you need `push output` instead.

Comment: "push dword [input]  ; Put into stack" thank you for pointing that out, suppose to be input2 pushed, typo. I put in **jmp** because I thought it was needed to call the next function as if it was like a C/C++ function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize EDX - either zero it (`xor edx, edx`) and use unsigned operations, or sign extend EAX into it (`cdq`)

---

IDIV does as follows ([link](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html)):

> Divides (signed) the value in the AX, DX:AX, or EDX:EAX registers
> (dividend) by the source operand (divisor) and stores the result in
> the AX (AH:AL), DX:AX, or EDX:EAX registers. The source operand can be
> a general-purpose register or a memory location.
>
> The action of this
> instruction depends on the operand size (dividend/divisor), as shown
> in the following table: IDIV Results [header]Operand
>
> [image]

Since you're dividing by EBX, it would take the dividend from EDX:EAX. You didn't initialize EDX to zero and therefor got junk result.

Comment: In general you need to _sign extend_ `eax` into `edx`: zeroing `edx` is only correct if `eax` is always positive.

Comment: @gsg - Correct, fixing

Comment: ok done but I am getting the same errors. Looking back on my book it uses idiv with cdq but uses ecx instead of ebx.

Comment: @user2922055, Where exactly do you populate `output` with the results? it seems like you're just leaving them on the stack

Comment: For signed `idiv`, use `cdq`.  For unsigned `div`, use `xor edx,edx`.    See [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593) for more about mostly unsigned division, and [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36464879) about signed and unsigned division.

Answer (score 1):

The result is consistent with your use of the stack.

The first three "push" of your code, leave the stack as

- 100000000
- 100000000
- 1869375819 (corresponding to string "Kilobytes: %d..." of your data.

When your code reaches the printOut, you overwrite the topmost value with the address of the string to printf. So your stack is :

- (*address of printf string*)
- 100000000
- 1869375819 (corresponding to string "Kilobytes: %d..." of your data.)

And printf prints these two values.

In fact, appears that you don't need all that push/pop. The only place where the stack is needed is in the call to printf. It must be :

- (*address of printf string*)
- (result of kilobyte: code)
- (result of megabyte: code)

As you saved the value into input (to use in kilobyte:) and input2 (to use in megabyte:),
you don't need to pop anything.

you can use :

```
kilobyte:
   mov eax, [input]
   cdq
   mov ebx, 1024
   idiv ebx
   mov [input], eax
```

So, input now contains the result of idiv. Similarly, in megabyte :

```
megabyte:
   mov eax, [input2]
   cdq
   mov ebx, 1048576
   idiv ebx
   mov [input2], eax
```

As in the previous code, now, input2 contains the result you want.
Finally, in printOut :

```
printOut:
   push [input2]
   push [input]
   push $output
   call printf
```

Good luck coding.

Comment: Note that `1024` is a power of 2, so you'd actually want `sar dword [input], 10` to do an arithmetic right shift.

Comment: (`sar` rounds toward -Infinity, not toward zero like `idiv`, so to get the exact same semantics you'd want to do some extra fixup to adjust by 1 depending on the sign bit of the value being right-shifted, like C compilers do.)