# When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?

Tags: assembly, x86, division, integer-division, sign-extension

I had a test todayand the only question I didn't understand involved converting a doubleword to a quad word.

That got me thinking, why/when do we sign extend for multiplication or division? In addition, when do we use instructions like cdq?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Use [`cdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo) / [`idiv`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv) for signed 32-bit / 32-bit => 32 bit division,

`xor edx,edx` / `div` for unsigned.**

With the dividend in EAX to start with, and the divisor specified as an operand to DIV or IDIV.

```
   mov  eax, 1234
   mov  ecx, 17
   cdq                   ; EDX = signbit(EAX)
   idiv  ecx             ; EAX = 1234/17     EDX = 1234%17
```

If you zero EDX/RDX instead of sign-extending into EDX:EAX before `idiv`, [you can get a large positive result for -5 / 2, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717317/dividing-with-a-negative-number-gives-me-an-overflow-in-nasm/51717463#51717463).

Using the "full power" of 64 / 32-bit => 32-bit division is possible, but not safe unless you know the divisor is large enough so the quotient doesn't overflow.  (i.e. you can't in general implement `(a*b) / c` with just `mul` / `div` and a 64-bit temporary in EDX:EAX.)

Division raises an exception (#DE) on overflow of the quotient.  On Unix/Linux, [the kernel delivers SIGFPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio) for arithmetic exceptions including divide errors.  With normal sign or zero-extended divide, overflow is only possible [with `idiv` of `INT_MIN / -1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378104/why-does-integer-division-by-1-negative-one-result-in-fpe/46378352) (i.e. the 2's complement special case of the most negative number.)

---

As you can see from the insn ref manual (link in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki):

- one-operand `mul` / `imul`: `edx:eax = eax * src`
- two-operand `imul`: `dst *= src`.  e.g. **`imul ecx, esi`** doesn't read or write eax or edx.

---

- `div` / `idiv`: divides `edx:eax` by the src.  quotient in `eax`, remainder in `edx`.  There's no form of `div` / `idiv` that ignores `edx` in the input.
- [`cdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv) sign-extends `eax` into `edx:eax`, i.e. broadcasts the sign bit of `eax` into every bit of `edx`.  Not to be confused with `cdqe`, the 64-bit instruction that is a more compact form of `movsxd rax, eax`.

  Originally (8086), there was just `cbw` (`ax = sign_extend(al)`) and `cwd` (`dx:ax = sign_extend(ax)`).  The extensions of x86 to 32bit and 64bit have made the mnemonics slightly ambiguous (but remember, other than `cbw`, the within-eax versions always end with an `e` for Extend).  There is no dl=sign_bit(al) instruction because 8bit mul and div are special, and use `ax` instead of `dl:al`.

---

Since the inputs to `[i]mul` are single registers, you never need to do anything with `edx` before a multiply.

If your input is signed, you sign-extend it to fill the register you're using as an input to the multiply e.g. with `movsx` or `cwde` (`eax = sign_extend(ax)`).  If your input is unsigned, you zero extend.  (With the exception that if you only need the low 16 bits of the multiply result, for example, [it doesn't matter if the upper 16 bits of either or both inputs contain garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in/34377712#34377712).)

---

For a divide, you always need to zero or sign extend eax into edx.  Zero-extending is the same as just unconditionally zeroing edx, so there's no special instruction for it.  Just `xor edx,edx`.

`cdq` exists because it's a lot shorter than `mov edx, eax` / `sar edx, 31` to broadcast the sign bit of eax to every bit in edx.  Also, shifts with immediate count > 1 didn't exist until 186 and were still 1 cycle per count, so on 8086 you'd have to do something even worse (like branch, or rotate the sign bit to the bottom and isolate + `neg` it).  So `cwd` in 8086 saved a lot of time/space when it was needed.

---

In 64bit mode, sign and zero extending 32bit values to 64bit is common.  The ABI allows garbage in the high 32bits of a 64bit register holding a 32bit value, so if your function is only supposed to look at the low 32bits of `edi`, you can't just use `[array + rdi]` to index the array.

So you see a lot of `movsx rdi, edi` (sign extend), or `mov eax, edi` (zero-extend, and yes it's more efficient to use a different target register, because Intel mov-elimination doesn't work with `mov same,same`)

Comment: Sorry - I always get mixed up with division in Assembly because I get confused with the registers. I thought that that the dividend was always placed in eax/ax and the one-operand instruction was just div/idiv ebx (or whatever register). Which would perform effectively eax / ebx with the quotient in eax and the remainder in edx. My exam showed us using cdq before we called idiv on EAX containing 71 and another register containing -4. Why is this? We were using the entirety of each register I don't understand why we needed one of them to be a quadword.

Comment: @Koronakesh: Read the first line of my answer, and/or Intel's insn ref manual.  `idiv ebx` does `eax = (edx:eax)/ebx` and `eax = (edx:eax)%ebx`. `edx` is always the high half of the dividend, and the explicit operand is always the divisor.  There's no form of `div` / `idiv` that ignores `edx` the way the 2 and 3-operand forms of `imul` only produce a single-register result.

Comment: Okay - this is making sense now. Are there requirements on the size of the dividend compared to the divisor? Also, do instructions like cdq exist simply because it's 1 byte less costly than something like sub edx, edx?

Comment: @Koronakesh:  `cdq` exists because it's a lot shorter than `mov edx, eax` / `sar edx, 31` to broadcast the sign bit of eax to every bit in edx.  `xor edx,edx` *zero*-extends, which is different from sign-extending.  Also, shifts with count > 1 didn't exist until 286, so it would have been really horrible to need a loop.  As for size limits, yes, if you read the instruction reference manual, you'll see that `div` faults if the quotient overflows the operand-size (e.g. 32bits).