# Why IDIV with -1 causes floating point exception?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

As far as I understood, `idiv %ebx` will divide `edx:eax` (concatenated into 64-bit value, in that order) with 32-bit `ebx`.

However, when I try to divide `0x00000000:0xfffffffb` (0 and -5) with `0xffffffff` (-1), I get a floating-point exception.

Can someone explain why? I'm quite puzzled why this is happening because I'm not dividing by 0 after all.

---

**Note** that I know I need to sign extend `edx:eax` to achieve what I want, which is to calculate `-5/-1`. However, even without sign extension the below should 
not cause an FPE.

[image: gdb screenshot]

Comment: Related question: [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46378104/1857492)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note that I know I need to sign extend `edx:eax` ...

If you don't sign-extend `eax`, `edx:eax` is interpreted as 64-bit signed number:

In your case, this would be 0x00000000fffffffb which is 4294967291 (and not -5).

`div` and `idiv` will cause an exception in two cases:

- You divide by zero
- The division result is not in the range that can be represented by the `eax` register

`eax` can hold signed numbers in the range from -2147483648 to +2147483647, but -4294967291 lies outside that range. You'll get an exception.

> should not cause an FPE.

Indeed, `div` and `idiv` will cause an "integer division exception", not "a floating-point exception".

However, many OSs will show the message "floating point exception"; POSIX defines SIGFPE as covering any arithmetic exception.

Answer (score 2):

As I was looking for a way to sign-extend `edx:eax` while I was waiting for an answer to this question, I accidentally found the answer myself.

As indicated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36465045/1857492), it turns out FPE (floating-point exception) is raised on all divide-errors, including when quotient of division overflows. The linked answer also says that usually, only `-1` causes this quotient overflow.

The solution is to sign-extend with `cdq` instruction, instead of zeroing out `%edx`.