# MOVZX and CWD - Are they interchangeable?

Tags: assembly, x86, division, instruction-set

I have these two code snippets:

```
mov   ax, word [wNum2]
cwd
div   word [wNum3]
mov   [wAns16], dx
```

```
movzx eax, word [wNum2]
;cwd
div   word [wNum3]
mov   [wAns16], edx
```

The first produces the correct answer, the second will give me an answer that is a hundred or so off unless I uncomment `cwd`.

My question is that I thought `movzx` would zero everything out for me, and that would make `cwd` redundant. Have I completely misunderstood how they work? Can someone walk me through these code snippets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bare result can be equivalent or not - that depends on the value. The description of [CWD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo) states

> Doubles the size of the operand in register AX, EAX, or RAX (depending on the operand size) by means of sign extension and stores the result in registers DX:AX, EDX:EAX, or RDX:RAX, respectively. The CWD instruction copies the sign (bit 15) of the value in the AX register into every bit position in the DX register.

So if the value in `AX` is smaller than or equal to 32,767 (15 bit MAX), the result of it is equivalent to `MOVZX` (zero extend) and `MOVSX` (sign extend). But if the value is bigger than 32,767 it would *only* be equivalent to `MOVSX`. Usually `MOVZX` would be used in combination with `DIV`(unsigned division) and `MOVSX` in combination with `IDIV`(signed division).

But there remains the problem of where the result will be stored:
`CWD` stores the 32-bit result in two 16-bit registers `DX:AX`, while the `MOV?X` instructions store it in the 32-bit register `EAX`.

This has consequences on the following [`DIV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) instruction. The first part of your code uses the 32-bit value in `DX:AX` as input, while the second approach assumes `EAX` to be the input of a 16-bit `DIV`:

```
F7 /6   DIV r/m16   M   Valid   Valid   Unsigned divide DX:AX by r/m16, with result stored in AX ← Quotient, DX ← Remainder.
```

which makes the result unpredictable, because `DX` is undefined and the higher half of `EAX` is unused in the division.

Comment: You should probably mention that you normally want to *zero*-extend before `div` (i.e. `xor edx,edx`), and only sign-extend before `idiv`.  [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36464879) and [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38416896)

Answer (score 3):

No, MOVZX is zero extension, not sign.  And CWD sign-extends AX into DX:AX (like you want before IDIV, not DIV).

`movSx eax, word [wNum2]` is a more efficient way to do `mov ax,mem` + CWD*E*, not CWD.  (If your inputs are known to be non-negative when treated as signed, sign and zero extension do the same thing).

[What does cltq do in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/45386217) has a table of cbw/cwde/cdqe and the equivalent movsx instruction, and what cwd/cdq/cqo do (and the equivalent mov/sar).

**None of these things are what you want before unsigned `div`**: use `xor edx,edx` to zero DX, the high-half input for 32/16 => 16-bit division.

See also [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36464879)

---

To avoid false dependencies from writing partial registers, on most recent CPUs the most efficient thing would be to do a movzx load just to get your 16-bit value into AX without merging into the previous value of RAX/EAX.  Similarly, xor-zeroing isn't (usually?) recognized as a zeroing idiom on partial registers so you want 32-bit operand-size even if you're only going to read the low half of

```
   movzx eax, word [wNum2]      ; zere extend only to avoid false dep from merging into EAX
   xor   edx, edx               ; high half dividend = DX = 0
   div   word [wNum3]
   mov   [wAns16], dx           ; store remainder from DX, not EDX
```

Your code storing 32-bit EDX into `[wAns16]` is presumably a bug, assuming there's only 2 bytes of space there before you step on whatever comes after it.