# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - C calling Assembly code for prime testing

Tags: c, x86-64, nasm

I have an assembly language code I'm calling from C but I keep getting error: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** I don't know what's the cause.

```
; this is the assembly code
section .text

global isPrime

isPrime: mov ecx, 2
.test:   cmp ecx, [rsi]
         jle .doif
         jg .prime

.doif:   mov eax, [rdi]
         mov edx, 0
         mov ebx, [rsi]
         div ebx
         cmp edx, 0
         jle .notPrime
         jg .checkAgain
.notPrime:
         mov eax, 1
         ret

.checkAgain:
         inc ecx
         jmp .test

.prime: mov eax, 0
         ret
```

The C code:

```
// C code

#include <stdio.h>

extern int isPrime(int *number, int *mValue);

int main() {
    int limit, m, input = 0;
    printf("Enter the limit of the prime numbers:");
    input = scanf("%d", &limit);
    while (input != 1) {
        printf("Not a number!\n");
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        printf("Enter the limit of the prime numbers:");
        input = scanf("%d", &limit);
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= limit; ++i) {
        m = i / 2;
        int flag = isPrime(&i, &m); //this is what I'm trying to implement
        // for (int j = 2; j <= m; j++) {
        //     if (i % j == 0) {
        //         printf("Number %d is not prime\n", i);
        //         flag = 1;
        //         break;
        //     }
        // }
        printf("%d\n", flag);
        if (flag == 0)
            printf("Number %d is prime\n", i);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Enter the limit of the prime numbers:10
0
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the commented part in the C code is what I want to write in assembly but got the error I mentioned above. From my research, I'm trying to write a memory address I do not have access to. The error is from assembly code but I don't know where exactly, please any possible solutions?

Comment: step through the assembler with your debugger

Comment: How do you compile and link your code?

Comment: Besides the calling-convention problem, `isprime` could be a *lot* more efficient.  After checking if it's greater than 2 and odd (`test byte [rdi], 1`), you can increment by 2 so you only try odd divisors starting with 3. You only need to check up to sqrt(n), i.e. when `n / trial_divisor <= trial_divisor`.  Also, it makes no sense to have the caller compute `n/2` or `sqrt(2)` and pass it as another arg; that's something `isprime` should be doing itself, like `mov` / `shr`, or with the divisor >= quotient trick.

Comment: See [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965) on codereview.  Also, if you have a conditional branch inside the loop, normally more efficient to lay it out so it's not-taken in the normal case.  i.e. you should lay it out like `if(remainder == 0) return 0`, so `test edx,edx` / `jz .prime`.  Also, it's called "isprime", but it returns 0 (false) for prime numbers, true for composite?

Answer (score 3):

System V x86_64 calling convention requires registers `rbx`, `rsp`, `rbp`, `r12`, `r13`, `r14`, `r15` to be preserved during function call. You use `ebx` register as a part of `rbx` but don't preserve it.

Straightforward solution is to preserve it on stack:

```
bits 64
section .text

global isPrime

isPrime: push rbx
         mov ecx, 2
.test:   cmp ecx, [rsi]
         jle .doif
         jg .prime

.doif:   mov eax, [rdi]
         mov edx, 0
         mov ebx, [rsi]
         div ebx
         cmp edx, 0
         jle .notPrime
         jg .checkAgain
.notPrime:
         pop rbx
         mov eax, 1
         ret

.checkAgain:
         inc ecx
         jmp .test

.prime:  pop rbx
         mov eax, 0
         ret
```

Note: there are two return points, so you have to restore `rbx` before each return.

It is also possible to save register before modification for each iteration. It saves one instruction of code size at the cost of executing push/pop every time through the loop.  `div` is slow, but this might be even slower on some modern CPUs. (Example how not to do):

```
...
.doif:   push rbx       ; don't do this, save/restore around the whole function
         mov eax, [rdi]
         mov edx, 0
         mov ebx, [rsi]
         div ebx
         pop rbx
...
```

Better solution is to use scratch register which is allowed to be modified instead of `ebx`.

```
         mov r8d, [rsi]
         div r8d
```

Or even divide by value in memory:

```
        div dword [rsi]
```

Some another improvements:

- For performance reason you can load values into registers at the beginning.
- `jle` instruction is redundant: CPU continue to execute correct branch if `jump if greater` is not executed.
- `cdq` instruction may be used to extend value in `eax` into `edx:eax`. Note: it behaves differently from `mov edx,0` because it extends sign bit. However we receive pointers to signed integers, so in theory we should be using `cdq` and `idiv`, not zero-extend and `div`.  (You don't want `cdq` + `div`; if your input was negative, `div` will treat it as huge unsigned, and [fault when the quotient doesn't fit in 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464879/when-and-why-do-we-sign-extend-and-use-cdq-with-mul-div).)
- For equality to zero `test edx,edx` may be used instead of `cmp edx,0`, these instructions are one byte shorter [and equal or faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg). Then `jz/jnz` conditional jump is more appropriate for semantic meaning, but the same machine instruction as `je`/`jne`.
- A similar x86 peephole optimization is [zeroing a register with `xor eax, eax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)
- You can increment `ecx` unconditionally. It saves one jump instruction.

---

**But there is logic error in your original code: all divisions are by the same value.** For prime test you should divide by all values sequentially.  (Or just by odd values, after checking once for an even number, so you can increment your counter by 2.)

```
         div ecx
```

So final code is:

```
section .text

global isPrime

isPrime: mov edi, [rdi]      ; load the pointed-to integers
         mov esi, [rsi]      ;  better: pass by value in the first place
         mov ecx, 2          ; starting divisor, and anything signed-less-than this is assumed prime.

                           ; do {
.test:   cmp ecx, esi
         jg .prime           ; if(ecx > endpoint) return yes

         mov eax, edi
         xor edx, edx        ; zero-extend EAX into EDX:EAX, or use cdq/idiv for signed division
         div ecx
         inc ecx
         test edx, edx
         jnz .test         ; }while( n % ecx == 0)
     ;; composite if we left the loop this way
         mov eax, 1
         ret

.prime:  xor eax, eax      ; eax=0
         ret
```

You declared your C variables as signed `int`, but you're using unsigned `div` in asm.  Unsigned makes the most sense; normally people don't talk about negative primes.

Passing a 2nd arg in ESI/RSI doesn't make much sense; the upper bound divisor limit is part of the prime-testing algorithm, not something the caller should need to calculate for it.  `mov esi, edi` ; `shr esi, 1`.

You can actually stop much sooner for large numbers, at `sqrt(n)` instead of `n/2`.  Or when `n/divisor <= divisor`, so you don't actually have to compute a square root. See [a code-review answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204902/checking-if-a-number-is-prime-in-nasm-win64-assembly/204965#204965) for a loop that does that, and increments by 2.

Comment: The `jle` can be eliminated because they jump to the "fall throughs"

Comment: @CraigEstey there are some imperfections in original code but i tried to keep the example close to original as much as possible.

Comment: Better yet: Instead of using `rbx`,  use a register than _can_ be trashed by the callee: (e.g.) `r9`

Comment: I'm commenting here more for OP

Comment: @CraigEstey: Or since the code doesn't need to keep reloading `[rsi]` from memory, just `mov esi, [rsi]` and use `cmp ecx, esi` and `div esi`.  Or better, have the caller pass the numbers by value, not reference.  Or if you don't want to do that, `div dword [rsi]` is a drop-in replacement.  (dimich: The current edit to use R11 to save RBX is not what Craig meant; if you insist on reloading that value twice per loop, `mov r11d, [rsi]` / `div r11d`.  And if you were going to save/restore RBX, you'd do it outside the loop.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I made that edit before the comment appeared. I also thought about using another register for divisor but it is out of scope of OP question. There are many things to impove in the code.

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of things to improve.   Even more after your proposed changes, unfortunately: you put the push/pop inside the loop, instead of around the whole function.  And instead of just using a different register, you made the loop code even more clunky.  You achieved correctness, but *not* in a way I'd recommend anyone learn from.   (See my codereview answer [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965) for code hat sucks as little as possible, given that it's doing trial division.  But that's a whole `main`, not separate `isprime`)

Comment: In that codereview answer, look at the code starting from `mov  r8d, [rsp+32]` which loads a scanf result.  It doesn't touch any call-preserved registers the whole function.  (And for Windows x64, that means avoiding ESI / EDI, unlike in x86-64 SysV. We have more low / legacy registers to play with here.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Just using different register implies changing operand size. I don't know OP's requirements and why they decided to pass pointers instead of values. The question is about reason of misbehavior, not request for optimization. If i had such task, i would not use assembly at all.

Comment: No it doesn't.  `r11d` and `r8d` are 32-bit registers, exact drop-in replacements for `ebx`.  Just like `r11` is a drop-in replacement for `rbx`.  https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86-64.  And `div dword [rsi]` is also a drop-in replacement for those few lines, if you don't want to hoist a load out of the loop.

Comment: I figured out I don't need the `ebx/rbx` registers to get the prime. Thank so much @PeterCordes for the links and @dimich for the code; and everyone for the comments.

Comment: @dimich: Oh BTW, your first code block is actually fine; you *do* have a version that pushes/pops around the whole function like how call-preserved registers should be used for efficiency; I missed that when writing an earlier comment.  Only the last 2 code blocks are bad suggestions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, it flew out of my head that r8-r15 have 32-bit parts :) Updated answer.

Comment: That's better.  Added a few updates myself, e.g. don't `or edx,edx`, and use either `cdq`;`idiv` or `xor edx,edx` / `div`; don't mix and match unless you have a signed dividend and unsigned divisor.  Since your division is unreachable for negative numbers, best to use an efficient zeroing instruction.  And just for simplicity and consistency; we're not code-golfing for minimal machine-code bytes at the expense of beginners being able to learn general good practices from it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is facing similar issue and needs help:

```
section .text
global isPrime

isPrime: mov ecx, 2
.test:   cmp ecx, [rsi]
         jle .doif
         jg .prime

.doif:   mov eax, [rdi]
         mov edx, 0
         div ecx
         cmp edx, 0
         jg .checkAgain
         mov eax, 1
         ret

.checkAgain:
         inc ecx
         jmp .test

.prime:  mov eax, 0
         ret
```