# Modulo in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, modulo

So I tried to do a program that does the modulo. I couldn't do so.
I tried using `idiv` or `div` but I just couldn't think off a way to do so. I will really appreciate if you can show me how to perform the modulo operation.

Answer (score 3):

Modulo operator is **%** or **\** in most assemblers.
The modulo operation represents the **remainder** after **dividend** is integer-divided by **divisor**.

For instance when dividend is `13` and divisor is `5`, then the modulo result is `13 % 5 = 3`. Unsigned division is provided in x86 by the instruction [DIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) and it depends on CPU mode:

```
; 8bit, works with dividend 0 .. (2^16 - 1)      64 KiB
MOV AX, 13  ; dividend
MOV CL,  5  ; divisor
DIV CL      ; Remainder 3 is now in AH, quotient 2 is in AL.

; 16bit, works with dividend 0 .. (2^32 - 1)      4 GiB
MOV AX, 13  ; lower 16 bits of dividend
MOV DX,  0  ; higher 16 bits of dividend
MOV CX,  5  ; divisor
DIV CX      ; Remainder 3 is now in DX, quotient 2 is in AX.

; 32bit, works with dividend 0 .. (2^64 - 1)     16 EiB
MOV EAX, 13  ; lower 32 bits of dividend
MOV EDX,  0  ; higher 32 bits of dividend
MOV ECX,  5  ; divisor
DIV ECX      ; Remainder 3 is now in EDX, quotient 2 is in EAX.

; 64bit, works with dividend 0 .. (2^128 - 1)   256 ???
MOV RAX, 13  ; lower 64 bits of dividend
MOV RDX,  0  ; higher 64 bits of dividend
MOV RCX,  5  ; divisor
DIV RCX      ; Remainder 3 is now in RDX, quotient 2 is in RAX.
```

It is rather more complicated with signed numbers using signed division [IDIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv), see the article [Modulo on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Just to be clear, `idiv` gives you the signed remainder just as easily, with `cdq` / `idiv` for 32-bit operand size for example (*[When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36464879)*).  But if you want modulo in the sense of Euclidean or floored division, not truncating (quotient rounds toward zero) where `-1 % 2 == -1`, then you'd want more instructions.

Comment: Following up on @PeterCordes  comment, remainder is zero or has the same sign as dividend. Mathematical modulo is zero or has the same sign as the divisor.

Comment: Right, but a lot of people misuse the terminology and are fine with remainder.  It's worth at least mentioning that remainder is easy, because a lot of people would search on "modulo" for an operation like the C `%` operator.  (Of course, people should just ask a compiler if it's something C can do directly.  https://godbolt.org/z/YKhvT3jGn

Comment: Just a tip, if you have to do modulo 2 (or some power of 2), just AND with that power of 2 minus 1. So for example, `n % 2` is the same as `n & 1`, `n % 4` is the same as `n & 3`, etc. Not only do you get the same result with `and`, it's also much faster. Unfortunately it only works with powers of 2.